# docker-compose conditionally build containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Our team is new to running a micro-service ecosystem and I am curious how one would achieve conditionally loading docker containers from a compose, or another variable-cased script.

An example use-case would be.
Doing front-end development that depends on a few different services. We will label those DockerA/D

Dependency Matrix

Feature1 - DockerA

Feature2 - DockerA and DockerB

Feature3 - DockerA and DockerD

I would like to be able to run something like the following

`docker-compose --feature1`

or

`magic-script -service DockerA -service DockerB`

Basically, I would like to run the command to conditionally start the APIs that I need.

I am already aware of using various mock servers for UI development, but want to avoid them.

Any thoughts on how to configure this?

Comment: We have a increasingly elaborate Python wrapper around docker-compose to support doing this locally, but for a first shot why not just write a script that accepts service names and passes them to docker-compose? `for project in projects; do docker-compose up $project; ...`. Is this for local development or running in production?

Comment: Local dev only. All the production stuff has a CD pipeline with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stop all services after creating them and then selectively starting them one by one. E.g.:

```
version: "3"

services:
    web1:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    web2:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
```

```
docker-compose up -d
    Creating network "composenginx_default" with the default driver
    Creating composenginx_web2_1 ... done
    Creating composenginx_web1_1 ... done
docker-compose stop
    Stopping composenginx_web1_1 ... done
    Stopping composenginx_web2_1 ... done
```

Now any service can be started using, e.g.,

```
docker-compose start web2
    Starting web2 ... done
```

Also, using linked services, there's the `scale` command that can change the number of running services (can add containers without restart).

Comment: I like this. I am putting together a PoC to discuss on Monday. Thanks.